# Constraining coef output using fit model or nls function

Tags: r, plot, nls, coefficients, mosaic

I have data on the photosynthetic activity of microalgae under increasing light. 
PAR: is the different light exposures, (x, independent variable)
ETR: is the photosynthetic activity (y, dependent variable).

```
PAR ETR
1   0.409090909
46  18.81818182
126 51.54545455
234 93.6
404 173.1428571
656 246
816 272
```

i was able to plot the point for a sample and get the curve. But i want to fit these points to a specific non-linear model using this formula:
ETR= PAR/((a*PAR^2)+(b*PAR)+c)
I used the Nls function as part of the mosaic package that uses the nls function as shown in the code:

```
TABLE=read.table("sample 2.txt", header = TRUE)
TABLE
plotPoints(ETR~PAR, data= TABLE)
f<-fitModel(ETR ~ PAR/((a*PAR^2)+(b*PAR)+c),data = TABLE, start = list(a=0, b=0.004, c=1))
coef(f)
plotFun(f, add=TRUE)
```

My results:

```
> TABLE=read.table("sample 2.txt", header = TRUE)
> TABLE
  PAR         ETR
1   1   0.4090909
2  46  18.8181818
3 126  51.5454546
4 234  93.6000000
5 404 173.1428571
6 656 246.0000000
7 816 272.0000000
> plotPoints(ETR~PAR, data= TABLE)
> f<-fitModel(ETR ~ PAR/((a*PAR^2)+(b*PAR)+c),data = TABLE, start = list(a=0, b=0.0035, c=1))
> coef(f)
            a             b             c 
 2.921397e-06 -2.027561e-03  2.718527e+00 
> plotFun(f, add=TRUE)
```

The problem is i do not want to have negative values for coef a,b, and c. This is because i am going to need these coefficients to get biological factors ETRmax= 1/b+2ac, Ek= c/b+2ac, alfa= 1/c which cannot be negative. I also need to use the Gauss-newton least square method and not the other algorithms where i can specify lower and upper bounds. I have tried to use the port algorithm to specify lower bounds of 0, but the problem is that b was 0, and i do not want b to be 0, i want all my variables to be greater than 0. I have tried many things but I can't solve this problem. I hope that you can help me with this, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify lower bounds with the `lower = c(0, 0, 0), alg = "port"` :

```
fitModel(ETR ~ PAR/((a*PAR^2)+(b*PAR)+c), data = TABLE, 
  start = list(a = 0, b = 0.0035, c = 1), lower = c(0, 0, 0), alg = "port")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already tried this, and b is 0, which i do not want. i want all coef to be greater than 0

Comment: It is going to drive it to the lower bound.  You can use a small number instead of 0.

Comment: Thank you, this works. I think R is going to choose the smallest positive value possible when it needs to correct for negative coef values. But i was wondering if i could tell R that i want my variables a> 0, b>0 and c>0 without constraining it to certain value/lower bound for each. I just want my coef results to be positive.

Comment: There is no minimum on such open sets.  For any proposed solution on such a set you will be able to find another proposed solution that produces a lesser objective value.  For example, the minimum of x^2 on the closed set x >= 0 is 0 but there is no minimum  on the open set x > 0.  For any x', x'/2 will give a smaller objective.

Comment: update: what i did was removing some data point from my data when i got negative coef. I tried to simulate the "model" curve with my data by removing the data points that were laying outside the "normal" shape of my model curve. This way i got positive coef. I know it is overfitting and modifying my data, but i think by putting constraints on my coeff i was doing that as well.

Comment: You could also try using robust nonlinear least squares.  `library(robustbase);
nlrob(ETR ~ PAR/((a*PAR^2)+(b*PAR)+c), data = TABLE, 
  start = list(a = 0, b = 0.0035, c = 1), lower = c(a = 0, b = 0, c = 0), upper =  c(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1), method = "MM")`